# Android Custom Bar Graph Layouts Not Adding

Tags: java, android, user-interface, graph

I'm trying to create my own custom bar graph in Android but I am having issues. The graphing libraries that I've seen don't offer the flexibility and customization that I need. Anyway, I'm in the beginning phases and have a really basic layout that is essentially the placeholders of where the "bars" will be placed. The xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/sectioned_borders"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="238dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sectioned_borders"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="238dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sectioned_borders"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="238dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

each FrameLayout is a section where I'm going to place the bars in the layout. Now, I want to place the bars dynamically since it can vary as to how many bars are present. So I put together a basic class and activity to just get something drawn in the section. I have the following class that contains "Bar" information:

```
package com.example.graph.resources;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class Bar {

   private final static int MAX_PERCENT = 100;
   private final static int MIN_PERCENT = 0;

   private int percent = 0;
   private String buttonText = "";
   private String barID = "";
   private Drive barDrive;   
   public TableLayout barLayout;

   public Bar(Context context, int percent, String buttonText, String barID, int width) {
      this.percent = (percent >= 0 && percent <= 100) ? percent : 0;
      this.buttonText = (buttonText != null) ? buttonText : "";
      this.barID = (buttonText != null) ? buttonText : "";

      barDrive = new Drive();

      // Create bar view
      TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
      TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(46, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
      tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

      FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(tableLayout.getContext());
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(tableLayout.getHeight() * 0.9));
      frameParams.leftMargin = 3;
      frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

      // Create Views (bars)
      View viewUnderlay = new View(frameLayout.getContext());
      LayoutParams viewUnderlayParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      viewUnderlay.setLayoutParams(viewUnderlayParams);

      View viewOverlay = new View(frameLayout.getContext());
      LayoutParams viewOverlayParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);      
      viewOverlay.setLayoutParams(viewOverlayParams);
      viewOverlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


      // combine views
      frameLayout.addView(viewUnderlay);
      frameLayout.addView(viewOverlay);
      tableLayout.addView(frameLayout);
      this.barLayout = tableLayout;      
   }

   // Maybe more advantageous to make this a separate class...
   private class Drive {

      private int driveNumber = 0;
      private int value = 0;

      public Drive() {
         // TODO Default Drive Info
      }

      private Drive(int driveNumber, int value) {
         // TODO Setup Drive Info
      }


   }

}
```

As you can see. The "Bar" class just sets some member data and then I have the "bar" layout that I try to add here. So in my main activities class I just try to populate the first frame. My main class is then:

```
package com.example.bargraphtest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.bargraphtest2.R;
import com.example.graph.resources.Bar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   LinearLayout la;
   FrameLayout frame1;
   Context ctx;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_graph_base_layout); 

      frame1 = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
      ctx = this;
      ViewTreeObserver vto = frame1.getViewTreeObserver(); 
      vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
          @Override 
          public void onGlobalLayout() { 
             frame1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
             //test with frame 1
             int testPadding = 3;
             int barCount = 3;

             int width = (frame1.getWidth() - ((barCount + 1) * testPadding)) / barCount;

             for(int i = 1; i <= barCount; i++){
                Bar bar = new Bar(ctx,i * 10, "1", "bar" + i, width);
                frame1.addView(bar.barLayout);
             }
             frame1.refreshDrawableState();
          } 
      }); 
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}
```

So, I try running this and I only get my generic layout (in xml). I don't get the (3) bars. When I debug the code below and I step through when the bars are getting created (the layouts), the width and height in the layoutparams are not being set correctly. I see negative values here, which is right for MATCH_PARENT but not for the actual width. I see a legit value for the calculated width. So... What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions/help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: since this was posted last night, I'll bump it up to make sure it didn't get buried.

Answer (score 0):

Alright all, I think I figured it out. So, there's two things to consider here... First, when defining the LayoutParams, make sure you are creating the parameters based off of the parent container not the container/layout that you are actually creating. For instance,in the above example, when creating a new TableLayout, I will define the LayoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams. Another thing, which I think is thee cause of all of the problems is the context... I wasn't using the same context throughout and it was messing up my layouts. So use the context that is generated with your activity/application. I was carrying over each child context and I think that is what was messing things up. Anyway, I was able toget a blue bar on the desired frame which is what I wanted to do for now. Hope this helps someone.